# Why does my Elementary OS show an ubuntu logo?

Tags: ubuntu, elementary-os

[image: elementary os freya logo changed]

what happened to the elementary os logo? why has it changed to an ubuntu

Comment: why not [ask](http://blog.elementary.io/ask) this question at the `elementary OS` website, they invite it, and i quote `Ask us anything`